# How to run command on subfolder of wildcard folders?

Tags: bash, unix, wildcard

Say I have this structure:

```
Some Folder 1/...
Some Folder 2/...
Adobe After Effects 2020/Scripts/
Adobe After Effects 2020/foo/
Adobe After Effects 2020/bar/
Adobe After Effects 2021/Scripts/
Adobe After Effects 2021/etc/
Adobe After Effects 2022/Scripts/
Another Folder/...
```

I want to change permissions on all the `Scripts` subfolders. I tried:

```
chmod -R o+rw 'Adobe After Effects */Scripts'
```

But that doesn't work. Any way to accomplish this using wildcards?

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do you have `Scripts` subdirectories under `Some Folder 1` and the other directories?  Or is it only the Adobe directories that should be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards are not expanded inside quotes, but you should be able to use this.
Note that the `*` is now outside the quotes.

```
chmod -R o+rw 'Adobe After Effects '*'/Scripts'
```

That will make the specified change on all files and directories with the 'Adobe After Effects' start and the `Scripts` subdirectory.  I'm not sure that `o+rw` is a good choice of permission, but you can fix that to suit yourself.  I'd be more likely to use `o+r,o-w`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
find -type d -name "Adobe After Effects *" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{.} find {.} -type d -name "Scripts" -exec chmod -R o+rw {} \;
```

It uses nested `find` as explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18101/249463